# Firefox 'no element found' - @RequestMapping

Tags: http, spring-mvc, firefox, annotations, content-type

I'm often getting "No element found" error in Firefox Console. I want to resolve this problem using @RequestMapping parameters. Below is Java function head:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/settings", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@PreAuthorize(EmailRolesConstants.HAS_ANY_EMAIL_ROLE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void setSettings(@RequestBody SettingsDto settings) {
      ...do something
}
```

I was using many ResponseMapping parameters but I'm getting code 415 or console error didn't disappear. Is some way to fix this in that way?

It's probably caused by empty response content.

Error appears in GET and POST methods. Only in Firefox.

Comment: You question is unclear for us to help you, could you please post more detail about your error? Like full stack exception and more code snippet.

Comment: There is no stack exception, only error in Firefox console. I can give more code.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an empty response, Firefox treats it as XML, which has a requirement that a root element must be present. If your response is JSON and you send an empty one, Firefox thinks you sent an empty XML, which is a violation.